# Substitute “[“ to [ using sed

Tags: sed, windows-shell

I’m trying to correct some errors of a file with the following input:

```
"[""test""]"
```

And I want to get this output:

```
["teste"]
```

I already tried the following commands:

```
sed -i s/"["/[/g *.csv
sed -i s/"]"/]/g *.csv
```

I get this error message:

> sed: -e expressou-me #1, character 7: Command `s' umfinished (s/// - mísseis delimitator)

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape `[` as it stands for [the bracket expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) opening in POSIX BRE. The closing bracket `]` can be left unescaped if it appears first (see point 1 in the standard quoted above).

```
sed -i 's/"\["/[/g; s/"]"/]/g' file
```

Comment: I had the same input

Comment: What do you mean by that, I don't understand. This `sed` expression is *not* the same as yours (notice `\[`).

Comment: Can you try this on your example: `echo '"[""test""]"' | sed 's/"\["/[/g; s/"]"/]/g'`?

Comment: i cant use the ' because i'm in windows, but i tested with out it and the result is the same...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
sed 's/"//g;s/[a-z]\{1,\}/\"&e"/'
```